# Update column set with sequence loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, sequence

I have a database (mailing) with roughly 533,000 records in it. I'm trying to create groups, essentially, that I can use to select a region of records. I'd like to create 10 groups of people.

So in 'mailing', I have a column named 'group'. And I want to insert a number (from 1 - 10) in each record. Once I hit 10, I want to loop the sequence over again starting with 1.

An example of how the database would look after updating the column 'group'

- firstname, lastname, 1
- firstname, lastname, 2
- firstname, lastname, 3
- firstname, lastname, 4
- firstname, lastname, 5
- firstname, lastname, 6
- firstname, lastname, 7
- firstname, lastname, 8
- firstname, lastname, 9
- firstname, lastname, 10
- firstname, lastname, 1
- firstname, lastname, 2 ...

Comment: Which DB engine? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Most databases can dynamically generate sequence/row numbers based on a sort order of an ordinal value such as an ID, this is better than hard coding values like this, what do you do when a record is deleted?

Comment: Jcl: Engine it is InnoDB

Comment: Alex K.: Thats a good question. I just haven't crossed that bridge yet. Ideally, if there are subscribers that are inserted or deleted, it'd be nice if it automatically updated the sequence loop in database. The purpose of the sequence in the db is because in ever other rotation when we mail out to subscribers, i need to select a different group of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned InnoDB, I'm assuming MySQL here.

So I'd say something like:

```
SET @grp:=-1;
UPDATE Table set `Group`=(@grp:=(@grp+1)%10) + 1;
```

That said, I wouldn't go with this approach, I'm just trying to answer the specific question

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82113/1

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error near 'group=@groups:=((@groups+1)%10)+1

Comment: I've made a slight edit. Also made a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82113/1 . Seems to work for me. Notice that `group` is a reserved word, so if you are using it for your field, you need to enclose it in backticks

Comment: That did the trick, i had to slightly modify things on my end, but I've got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the right way to manage exclusion lists and contact strategies. Instead, you should be keeping a list (in a table) of who is contacted during a particular mailing. Then, for the next mailing, you can choose people who were not mailed in the previous one.

If you do have some real business need to separate the contacts into ten equal-sized groups, then consider how this is going to be maintained:

- What happens when people are added/removed/deleted?
- When new people are added, do they go into the "next-to-be-mailed" group (so they get mailed quickly), or are they assigned into groups randomly?
- What happens when a new manager appears and wants 8 groups?  Or 12?

In any case, if you went ahead with this approach, I would suggest that you simply assign each person randomly:

```
update t
    set grp = floor(rand() * 10);
```

Comment: The answer to those questions is rather complicated as well. Basically, all the subscribers are split up into regions. 1 week we mail to "north east" region, which is a predefined number of states we select. But we don't want to mail to ALL subscribers in the "north east" region that week, only "group 1". Then the next time we mail to NE region, i can mail to group 2, then 3, and so on. 

As for how we'd manage new/deleted records, I have yet to figure out the proper way to sequence them in.